# DirectAccess 2012 R2 connection failing for Win8 with certificates

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

We're working on an implementation of DirectAccess using Windows Server 2012 R2.

The DA server is a single NIC behind the firewall with TCP/443 forwarded for IPHTTPS.

During the initial testing/setup, we set it up strictly for Windows 8.1 clients, using the username/password (computer account) to authenticate.  Everything worked beautifully.

Wanting to extend the testing to Windows 7 clients, we configured DA to use certificates for authentication.  We have an internal PKI infrastructure that has worked properly for everything else we've needed it for during the last 2 years.

Windows 7 clients, with the DirectAccess Connectivity Assistant, connect and work beautifully.  However, Windows 8.1 clients cannot.

We've checked the certificates and all seems good.  Using the DirectAccess Troubleshooter, we see that it connects successfully to the DA IPHTTPS URL, however it can't access any internal resources.  We can ping the internal DCE addresses x:y:z::1 & x:y:z::2 that it is my understanding are the DA server inside our network.

Are there any additional tools for troubleshooting this?  Can anyone point me in the right direction to determine why only Win8 clients won't connect with certificates?

Answer (score 0):

The initial getting started wizard in DA allows Windows 8 / 8.1 to connect using Kerberos Proxy (no certs). A full blown install using PKI mandates that all clients use certificates. Deploy the Computer certs to the Windows 8 / 8.1 and you will be fine.

Reference - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/dn197886.aspx

How does DirectAccess in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 simplify deployment?
In earlier versions of Windows Server, a PKI was required to deploy DirectAccess. DirectAccess used the PKI for server and client certificate-based authentication. Now Windows 8 sends client authentication requests by using a Kerberos proxy service running on the DirectAccess server. The Kerberos proxy service sends requests to domain controllers on behalf of the client. As a result, for simple deployments a PKI is not required to deploy DirectAccess, and IT administrator can use the Getting Started Wizard to configure DirectAccess in a few easy steps. For more complex deployment scenarios, PKI is still required.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can present some graphical representations of your problems 'cause every response to your question would only be assumptions.
Troubleshoot as follows:

1. Check to make sure the windows client is an Enterprise edition
2. If point 1 above is true, run the 'get-DaConnectionstatus' command on Powershell to see if the client can determine its location, otherwise get a windows enterprise edition.
   3.If both point 1 and 2 are true then check to make sure your group policies are well configured. Remember to separate the security groups for windows 7 and windows 8 clients.